# What is the send message throughput of MS Teams bot?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing an MS Teams app with a bot. Occasionally, the bot needs to send a proactive message to a subset of users who have installed the app.

We cannot send a message to multiple users at once. So we have to make one HTTP request per user per message. Given that batching is not possible and there are API rate limits, I want to know how scalable is this.

Specifically, I want to know the approximate time between when the first and the last user receive the messages if I send message to 5k users at once. What about 10k? 20k?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This document gives a lot of detail on the throttle limits, and the related time periods required: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did check this document. However, all the limits mentioned are with respect to one specific conversation or a channel. What I am looking for is the limit on how many times I can send a message to different users within a specific time period.

Comment: @annihilator, This document is about messaging limits check [limits-specifications-teams-messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams#messaging)